# Histogram equalization for non-images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a vector of values and I want to change the values somehow that its histogram is closer to the uniform distribution using MATLAB. I am aware of histeq in MATLAB that takes an image as input and assumes the densities are in 0-255 range.  I am looking for a more general version of histeq.

Comment: Why not scale your vector to be image like and use the image tools?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do a full scale contrast stretch, correct? If so this function will work. You can change K to be the largest value in your vector if you are not using 8 bit integers.

```matlab
function [result] = myfscs(image)
K=255;
A= min(image(:));
B= max(image(:));
P=K/(B-A); 
L=A*K/(B-A);
J = (P .* image - L);
result = uint8(J); % doesn't have to be a uint8 returned
```

Comment: This is only a linear mapping.  Are you aware of more general ways to do this, taking histogram of values into consideration to choose a proper (perhaps) nonlinear mapping?